# Changing the Index of Summation for Second Order Differential Equation - Power Series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, power-series

So far, the changing of the index of summation is quite straightforward.

However, at an example in my textbook, something happens that seems out-of-the-blue to me.

Working towards the recurrence relation, we have:

$$\sum^\infty_{n=0}(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}(x-1)^n-\sum^\infty_{n=0}(n+1)a_{n+1}(x-1)^{n+1}- ... $$

The right summation is where the index is changed, in order to change the power of $(x-1)^{n+1}$. So far so good. Skipping a few steps here, immediately giving the altered part:

$$ \sum^\infty_{n=1}na_n(x-1)^n$$

Now comes the weird part. When plugging this back into the equation, the textbook alters only $\sum^\infty_{n=1}$ into $\sum^\infty_{n=0}$, without making any other adjustments.

The whole picture being:

$$\sum^\infty_{n=0}(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}(x-1)^n-\sum^\infty_{n=0}na_n(x-1)^n- ... $$

Is it possible to just change the starting index without altering anything in your summation?
Or am I missing a certain intermediate step (or some other knowledge or relation)?

Image attached as reference of the whole question.

> [image]

Comment: The term for $n=0$ is zero. So the lower index bound gets shifted up and then the sum immedieately extended.

Comment: One other question, not related to the previous question but a practical one. 

Does the question placed require an answer in order to change the status to 'Solved'? 
As I can't find where or how to change the status of this question

Comment: No, there is no way to mark it as "solved" without answer. The next reasonable variant would be to find a duplicate, problems with index shifts should not be that rare. If you really want a clean closure of the question, you could also, perhaps after some time, write your own answer. Here I just expanded my comment into a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have a sum $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n+1), ~~ f(n)=na_n(x-1)^{n}.$$ This gets first changed via index shift to $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n).$$ Then the observation $f(0)=0$ is taken into account to change to the common index boundaries $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n).$$